# SQLITE db copy is failing for tablets

Tags: android

I am facing a strange stuation.

I am using the following code to create a sqlite db from assets folder. It is working without any issue for any phones. But for tablets, the copy is failing. For example: sample db is 526kb, but only 12kb is created for tablets. I can manually upload the file in emulator. But I really need the code works for tablets without any manual intervention for real tablets.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "C:/temp/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "sample.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2) {
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        } else {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {          
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {               
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
    * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created    empty database in the
    * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
    * This is done by transfering bytestream.
    * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        //System.exit(0);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName =  DB_PATH+DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath =  DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);      
    }

}
```

Comment: I checked /data/data/mypackage/databases folder permissions for Nexus S and Nexus 9 emulators. Both exactly same.

Comment: I also increased, or decreased the buffer size still same.

Comment: The issue appears only on tablets regardless whether it is Samsung or Xiami or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I found an obscure thread that said that certain types of objects get compressed when added to the assets folder.  If you name your database .db or .sql, it will get compressed.  You need to name it .jpg and it won't get compressed.  Then, when you copy the database from assets to the app's data folder at runtime, you can name it whatever you like:

```
private String DB_PATH = "";
private static String DB_IN = "mydatabase.jpg";
private static String DB_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    DB_PATH = myContext.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath() + "/databases/";

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_IN);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

Comment: Tried. Still same. No error message when creating and opening sample.jpg database. But when I try to query my table, it says "No table is found".

Comment: Run the app in the AVD, so that it copies the SQLite database from Assets to your data folder in the AVD.  Then, navigate to that data folder, and copy the database that is there to your desktop.  Then, use whatever tool you normally use to open the database to see if it is recognized as a valid SQLite database.  If not, it is because of the compression.  Make sure to uninstall your app each time you change anything associated with the database, otherwise, it will continue to use the previous version that was copied before.

Comment: If I manually uploaded db file from assets to emulator tablet, it works fine. I have just noticed one difference for permission between phone and tablet folders. In my package, there are cache and code_cache folders. For phone, their permissions are: drwxrwx--x, for tablets: drwxrws--x.  Not sure whether it is causing the issue. For phone: sample.db 526kB, sample.db-journal 8.5KB. But for tablet, only sample.db - 12kb